# Sign in with twitter in a iPhone application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter, twitter-oauth

We have seen sign in using facebook and google+ in most of the iphone apps, but not the sign in using twitter. I searched in the internet for such Twitter SDK for iOS, but couldn't find. And also, haven't seen apps using Twitter for user authentication.
My question is, Isn't there any SDK for iOS to sign in with Twitter? If its not, whats the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't implemented it myself, but they do have this: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/twitter-login

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know how it goes, if you think of it sometime.

Comment: Sure, Im willing to add sign in via twitter along with facebook and g+ for the app Im currently working on

Answer (score 0):

You can Try [this](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) simple and sweet . It's basically auth authentication .